# Drawing Custom Size Text on Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, textview, android-vectordrawable

I need to draw some text on a canvas. I've already added a rectangular box in canvas and my goal is to make this text fit within the box but no matter what I try, text never fits perfectly for all screen sizes.

One other thing is that this text is simple HTML.

```
TextView currDateLabel = new TextView(getContext());
currDateLabel.layout(0, 0, boxSize.x, boxSize.y);
currDateLabel.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.label_date));
currDateLabel.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
currDateLabel.setText(Html.fromHtml("Dec 11<sup><small><small>TH</small></small></sup>"));
currDateLabel.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Bitmap dateBitmap = currDateLabel.getDrawingCache(true);
// I've also tried setting the width of this Bitmap but it doesn't seem to do anything

this.canvas.drawBitmap(dateBitmap, boxPosition.x, boxPosition.y, null);
```

So to explain some of the variables here:

- `boxSize` is a `Point` object that stores width and height of the box that on canvas. **These values seems to have no effect on size of the `TextView` because I can see the text going outside the box.**
- `boxPosition` is a `Point` object that stores `x` and `y` position of the box on canvas.
- `R.dimen.label_date` is a value in `dimens.xml` files.

I have created multiple `dimens.xml` files (`values/dimens.xml`, `values-hdpi/dimens.xml`, `values-xhdpi/dimens.xml`, and so on)

I thought I can test most of the screen sizes and figure out the size of the text for each screen category. However it is not working how I expected.

These values are for **Samsung Galaxy S8**:

> Screen Width: 1440, Screen Height: 2768
>   Screen Density: 4.0
>   Screen Density DPI: 640
>   Screen Scaled Density: 4.0

These values are for **Samsung Galaxy S7**:

> Screen Width: 1440, Screen Height: 2560
>   Screen Density: 4.0
>   Screen Density DPI: 640
>   Screen Scaled Density: 4.0

They both fall under `XXXHDPI` category so they have the same font size but Galaxy S8 text fits in the box and Galaxy S7 text is too big and goes outside the box.

Am I missing something here?

Is there some completely different way for me to draw HTML text on Canvas?

## ==================================================

## EDIT:

To explain my use case in more details:

The box I am referring to is an SVG/Vector object.

`label_down.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="90dp"
    android:height="45dp"
    android:viewportWidth="90"
    android:viewportHeight="45">

    <path
        android:fillColor="?attr/labelColor"
        android:pathData="M 0 0 L 0 37.532 L 36.63 37.532 L 45 45 L 53.371 37.532 L 90 37.532 L 90 0 Z" />
</vector>
```

Then I create a `Bitamp` object from that vector and draw `Bitmap` on Canvas.

```
VectorDrawableCompat vectorDrawableCompat = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.label_down, theme);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawableCompat.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawableCompat.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
this.canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, someXPos, someYPos, null);
```

Doing this would result in something like this:

[image]

Now, my goal is to create text inside that box.

Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: i think there should be some other work around to achieve what you are looking for , may be you should try some thing other than making a box and drawing an html text in that box . if you can explain a lil bit of your task than people might help you more than putting text in that box .. just saying

Comment: @AdeelTurk I've modified my question with more details. Thanks

Comment: i have created a same ui for my chat application . i used 9.patch image as textview background and its working totaly fine in all devices and both orientations as well

Comment: so my point here is why are you drawing this vector and then trying to put text in this box you can do it other way right.. like and if you want bitmap of written text with this bg then you can get bitmap of that text view and use it where ever you want ..

Comment: @AdeelTurk that vector is part of much bigger vector and there are lot of other things on the canvas. I can't do it all of it as one bitmap because some parts of the vector are clickable and some are not. And the text changes based on other thing user does in the app so it can't be just static text in the box/vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this points out a difference between "sp" and "dp" units. You don't document in your question what the value of `label_date` is in your dimensions file. I assume, since it is a unit of text size, that you are using "sp" units.

If so, change "xxsp" to "xxdp" to check if you see a difference. I just tried this on a Nexus 5X API 26 emulator and a Galaxy S7 running Android 7.0 and the "dp" units fixed the problem with your HTML text. Here is what I saw:

**Nexus 5X API 26 Emulator**

[image]

**Galaxy S7 Device API Android 7.0**

[image]

**Update:** I was curious about what exactly is going on. It looks like the scaling factor for scaleable pixels (SP) is greater than one in the S7 settings. Go to "Settings->Display->Screen zoom and font" and set the "FONT SIZE" to the third hash mark. Your text shoud now display correctly.

You don't want your text to scale independently of your graphic, so, IMO, using density-independent pixels (DP) as the units for your text is the right thing to do to maintain consistency between your graphic and text.

**2nd update:** For a given screen size/density, as long as the size of your graphic is fixed and the displayed size of the font can change according to the device settings, you will continue to have the potential for the text not fitting. If you don't think that specifying density-independent pixels as a unit for the font, you can go ahead and use scaleable pixels but adjust the font size used in your code.  Something like this:

```
float fontScale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;
textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources()
    .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.label_date_sp) / fontScale);
```

This will adjust the effective scaling factor of the font back to 1.0. The downside here is that although you may specity, let's say, `14sp` for the font size, the actual displayed size would be different and would be smaller than other element that are also `14sp`. This has the same effect as specifying "DP" but will use the more standard "SP" units.

Comment: I will look into this more. But I did try DP. The problem with DP is font size doesn't get bigger with larger resolution sizes, which is the whole point of SP. Example: I've changes my "Font Size" and "Display Size" on my OnePlus 3 phone to be "Small". This means `16dp` font size will be really tiny inside the box because font won't get bigger. This might work it feels more like a workaround than a solution.

Comment: @th3pat3l You may want to take a look at [auto sizing](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html) that is available with Android 8.0 and in the support library. The problem with and sp widget bounded by a widget measured in dp is that sp and dp can change independently of one other. A font measured in dp should scale on larger screens just like your graphic widget will.

Comment: You had some great ideas and your 2nd update led me to a different direction where I was able to solve this. I created the box and `TextView` as a custom `View`. Took the box height and divided by 3 for example. And that gave me font size in `COMPLEX_UNIT_PX` (pixels). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTML text won't render properly as you can see, I recommend Drawing DOM objects into a canvas

[DOM Elements on Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas)

Comment: HTML text renders perfectly. The problem is the size of the `TextView` is too big. But I will take a look at the link. Thanks